Whatsapp Webhook endpoint verification failing
I'm experiencing issues setting up Webhook events to my system's endpoint. Every attempt fails, and the following error message appears in the developer console:
The callback URL or verify token couldn't be validated. Please verify the provided information or try again later.
I've been using ngrok during development, and everything worked perfectly. However, the issue arose when transitioning to the production environment.
Steps I've Tried:

Verified that the callback URL is correct. The same URL works when tested using Postman.
Logged requests in my API to check if the webhook request is reaching my server, but no requests are being logged.
Reached out to Meta support, but haven't received a response yet.
Searched extensively online, but haven't found a solution.

Additional Information:
The server uses HTTPS with a valid SSL certificate (checked with https://www.sslshopper.com).
No firewall restrictions seem to block incoming webhook requests.
My production endpoint is accessible publicly and responds correctly to other requests.
Has anyone faced similar issues? Any advice or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.

Created a proxy server with acceptable domain name, and it temporarly resolved the problem.
